# Simulating a Click on C# Web Browser at a specific point

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to force a mouse click within my webbrowser at a specific point.

I'm using the following code:

```
    public void DoMouseClick(int X, int Y)
    {
        //Call the imported function with the cursor's current position
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
    }



[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int cButtons, int dwExtraInfo);

    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;
```

However this code doesn't appear to be working at all, it isn't clicking there? I also am not sure whether this code actually moves the phsyical mouse or not, I need something that simulates a click not moves my mouse there and does the click.

I cannot use the HTMLElement stuff because that doesn't allow you to click a specific co-ordinate in the element, which I require, I need to click a very specific spot.

Could any one help with this

Answer (score 0):

I got this, I used it for some auto-clicker stuff.. I can't and will not take any credit for this, I even think I found the code here on stackoverflow..

```
[Flags]
public enum MouseEventFlags
{
    LeftDown = 0x00000002,
    LeftUp = 0x00000004,
    MiddleDown = 0x00000020,
    MiddleUp = 0x00000040,
    Move = 0x00000001,
    Absolute = 0x00008000,
    RightDown = 0x00000008,
    RightUp = 0x00000010
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetCursorPos")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool GetCursorPos(out MousePoint lpMousePoint);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

public static void SetCursorPosition(int X, int Y)
{
    SetCursorPos(X, Y);
}

public static void SetCursorPosition(MousePoint point)
{
    SetCursorPos(point.X, point.Y);
}

public static MousePoint GetCursorPosition()
{
    MousePoint currentMousePoint;
    var gotPoint = GetCursorPos(out currentMousePoint);
    if (!gotPoint) { currentMousePoint = new MousePoint(0, 0); }
    return currentMousePoint;
}

public static void MouseEvent(MouseEventFlags value)
{
    MousePoint position = GetCursorPosition();

    mouse_event
        ((int)value,
         position.X,
         position.Y,
         0,
         0)
        ;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MousePoint
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public MousePoint(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: SetCursorPosition(finx, finz);
                    MouseEvent(MouseEventFlags.LeftDown);
                    MouseEvent(MouseEventFlags.LeftUp); I tried this, but it isn't working, is this correct?